# SetThreadUILanguage on Windows XP vs. Vista+?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, localization, locale, embedded-resource

The [docs for `SetThreadUILanguage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374053%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) state that:

> **Windows XP:** The application can only set this parameter to 0. This
>   setting causes the function to select the language that best supports
>   the console display. For more information, see the Remarks section.

It later goes on (rather hidden in the middle of a paragraph):

> (...) Windows XP does not support a concept of thread user interface
>   language separate from thread locale. Therefore, this function changes
>   the thread locale on Windows XP. (...)

And this in fact seems to be what happens, that is, calling `SetThreadUILanguage` on Windows XP seems to amount to calling [`SetThreadLocale`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), while on Vista+ it seems to result in basically the same thing as calling [`SetThreadPreferredUILanguages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which isn't available on XP at all).

The docs are clear as mud to me, so my basic question probably is: Am I supposed to call `SetThreadUILanguage` on Windows XP to change the (preferred) UI langauge and is this properly documented somewhere, and on Windows 7, am I supposed to call this function at all, or should I call `SetThreadPreferredUILanguages`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's an old thread, but I'm curious if you found a solution? I'm dealing with the same issue and I'm totally perplexed by Microsoft's documentation. Here's what I learned so far:

1 `SetThreadLocale` is pretty much useless. I am not really sure what the heck it does. MSDN [page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) first states this:

> SetThreadLocale affects the selection of resources with a LANGUAGE
>   statement. The statement affects such functions as CreateDialog,
>   DialogBox, LoadMenu, LoadString, and FindResource. It sets the code
>   page implied by CP_THREAD_ACP, but does not affect FindResourceEx.

OK. I get this part. But then it has this "gem":

> Windows Vista and later: Do not use SetThreadLocale to select a user
>   interface language.

Now it's pure Microsoft :) So what the heck was all that hogwash in the paragraph above?

2 `SetThreadUILanguage` works only on Vista and later OS. On XP it does pretty much nothing, so unless you want to miss out on a large number of users that still stick with XP, this API is also useless for now. (It seems to do the job all by itself on Vista and later OS though.)

3 `SetThreadPreferredUILanguages` works on Vista and later OS only, so we're going back to the lack of XP support. From what I understand, if you include a bunch of languages in resources, say these three: US-English, French, German. When the resource loader loads it, say, in Switzerland a moronic Microsoft loader will pick US-English by default. So this API tells it what language to use. (I know, completely redundant, but, hey, remember, we're dealing with Microsoft.)

The issue that I can't seem to resolve is how to define UI language in XP. It is possible to use `FindResourceEx` for strings and dialogs (use `CreateDialogIndirect`), but what about file open/save dialogs or `GetOpenFileName` and property sheets or `CPropertySheet`?

So I'm curious how did you handle it?

Comment: I abandoned this path (as it was for testing out different options anyway). However, I seem to remember that in my test-program `SetThreadUILanguage` did in fact **work on XP**, (compiled with VS2010). But I'm not sure anymore and I can't find the test code atm. so you should really try whether it works on XP or not.

Comment: Experimentally archeived the following:
1. On XP you should call SetThreadLocale 
2. On Vista call SetThreadUILanguage and don't call SetThreadLocale
Note: if you call SetThreadUILanguage  and then SetThreadLocale, on machines like Korean Win 7, you'll get issues with standard dialogs like Open/Save. Strings like  AFX_IDP_ASK_TO_SAVE
 would be displayed as '????????'

Comment: @c00000fd: did you ever figure this one out? I tried using `SetThreadLocale()` in XP, but it has zero effect on what gets picked by `LoadString`, the dialog box functions etc. I dug a bit into this and it seems one field in the TEB gets set by `SetThreadLocale()`. That does get accessed by some internal function in ntdll.dll which has to do with resources, but the logic of these ntdll.dll functions is a puzzle to me.

Comment: You know I pretty much gave up on XP. My app still runs on it but with limited functionality. And if users complain I usually tell them this -- "sorry, I'm doing my best here. It is hard to do something when the OS maker doesn't care to fix bugs." This usually works. Plus people get it that it's a 15 year old OS.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Here's what I ended up doing. Mine is an MFC app, so I first call `AfxInitMUILanguage` on the `LANGID` that I get from `LCID` with `LANGIDFROMLCID` macro. Then call `SetThreadLocale` on LCID. Then check if it's Vista and up and if so call `SetThreadUILanguage` on LANGID you got above. That generally works. As for previous comment, I didn't know that `SetThreadUILanguage` worked on XP. I can't confirm that. I also haven't dug deep into those APIs themselves to see what's going on. If you find any undocumented methods for XP please post it here.

Comment: @c00000fd will do. Thanks for your response. And yes, `SetThreadUILanguage` works on XP, but not for the exact same purpose. It all seems to be messy up to Vista.